# Why isn't the variable being shown in PHP Mailer $subject?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've researched this particular issue here on Stackoverflow. As I was unable to find it, I concluded that I'm probably the only one who's ever had this little glitch.

More amusing: I know the solution is something rather trivial, and I feel silly that I can't put my finger on it  (LOL)

I am trying to display a variable in the **$subject** heading of my PHP mail-function.

The variable is displaying everywhere else. Including the Title, and the Body of the email.

But, not the **$subject.**

```
   $to = $email;
   $subject = 'Your transaction details have been received (ID : $tran_id)';
   $email_body = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>TRANSACTION ID : $tran_id</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
    <p>Dear $firstname,</p>
    <p>Thank you registering.</p>
    <p>Your transaction ID is :  $tran_id
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am guessing the single quotes are the cause of the issue.  But, can't figure it out.

Comment: please ... send your full code .. so can we understand .. easily .

Comment: Yes, of course.

Single quotes, versus double quotes )))))

I knew it was something silly

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar No they should add a [mcve]. No need to look over a complete project for a small problem that can be found easily like in this code.